# How to Plot Confusion Matrix in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am a beginner in PyTorch and machine learning in general. I have a code for training and testing an MLP to classify the MNIST dataset. I need to plot a confusion matrix for this but unfortunately I don't know how. I am providing the code for this. Please let know what code I should write for the confusion matrix. BTW, this is not my code, I got it from the internet. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import time

# enable GPU
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device('cuda')
else:
    device = torch.device('cpu')
    
print('Using PyTorch version:', torch.__version__, ' Device:', device)

# Build a simple MLP to train on MNIST
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(784, 128),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(128, 256),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(256, 512),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(512, 10),
    nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
)

# Load the training data
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST('data', train=True, download=True,
                     transform=transforms.Compose([
                            transforms.ToTensor(),
                            transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
                        ])),
    batch_size=64, shuffle=True)    

# Load the test data
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST('data', train=False, transform=transforms.Compose([
                            transforms.ToTensor(),
                            transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
                        ])),
    batch_size=64, shuffle=True)


# Define the optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

# Define the loss function
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()

# Train the model
def train(epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data = data.view(-1, 784)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))

# Test the model
def test():
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in test_loader:
            data = data.view(-1, 784)
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += criterion(output, target).item()
            pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
            correct += pred.eq(target.data.view_as(pred)).sum()

    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
    print('Test set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%) '.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))

start = time.time()

# main
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # Run the training loop
    # This is the loop you have to time
    for epoch in range(1, 10):
        train(epoch)

        
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

test() 
   
# Save the model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "mnist_mlp.pt")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use `sklearn` package.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay


cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm).plot()
```

the output will be something like this [image: confusion_matrix_example]

Here is [some extra documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html)

EDIT:

`y_test` will be the correct labels of the testing set, and `predictions` will be the predicted labels from your model.

Adapting the answer a bit to your code:

in this lines

```py
for data, target in test_loader:
```

`target` are the correct labels

and in this line

```py
pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
```

`pred` is your predicted label

as they are used in a for loop, you can add them one by one into their own arrays for later use

```py
y_test = []
predictions = []
...

   y_test.append(target)
   predictions.append(pred)
```

then at the end of the for loop you can use the ConfusionMatrixDisplay to plot your results

Comment: what would be my y_test and predictions?

Comment: Edited my test loop according to your suggestion. But now, I keep getting "ValueError: unknown is not supported" error.